# Rails and MySQL -- setting root password dilemma

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, root

I am kind of facing a dilemma right now - I know it is insecure to leave my root MySQL account without a password, but I feel like it would be a big hassle when working on big projects with many users to keep modifying the `database.yml` file's development info to reflect my personal root account password every time I pull from git and then to keep switching it back before pushing.  Is there a way to have a password for root and yet not have to keep modifying the database.yml file's development area every time I pull from the git repo after others have worked on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a template database.yml and call it something different, like database.yml.template or something. Then have git ignore the actual database.yml file which you now can configure for your own personal settings. The real configuration will not be touched by git pull and will not be accidentally pushed to the source repo either.

Comment: so what does the template do here?

Comment: It makes it easy for new devs to see exactly what needs to be in the file. When you first check out a project, you copy the template to database.yml and edit it for your personal settings.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want to add it to `.gitignore`? So it there will be frozen version of `database.yml` in the repo.